# How to use Mojarra 2.2.10 in Glassfish

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish, mojarra

I usually download the latest Mojarra jar from https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/ or http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/ and replace the old 'javax.faces.jar' file in C:\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\modules\

With Mojarra 2.2.10, they did not upload the new jar file to either of the above sites, I can only get the following 2 jar files:

- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.2.10
- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.10

These two files do not work in Glassfish.

Should I combine them manually and how? Or am I doing it the wrong way to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look again. The file you are looking for *IS* available for download!

See here:
https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.10/

Or here: Direct link: https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.10/javax.faces-2.2.10.jar